# $("Div").load() appending html page after completion of $(document).ready() when written inside $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Sorry if this type of question is already been answered. 
I am trying to add a page using `$("Div").load()` inside `$(document).ready()`. 
Page is getting loaded but it is not showing anything inside its' variables.

Steps in my code:

1. Page starts loading
2. Value come from back-end code (spring java)
3. Loading a specific page when values are present and show them on page.
4. If values are null, do not load page.

Jquery version: "2.1.3"

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(
            if(condition1){
                var var1= data //some json data;
                $('#divId').load('url/mypage.jsp');
                if(condtition == true){
                    myFunctionToProcessData(var1);          
            }
            }
)
```

I have tried ajax call, but its not working.

After completion, I can see my page is loaded and appended in division but not showing on UI and have empty variables.

Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your code at all. Did you write this, or only copy and paste some lines you found on the internet... It doesn't make sense to me or isn't this the complete code?

Comment: This is not your problem.

Comment: Apologies, but i could not reveal my whole code, I have just made one template to give an idea about my issue. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. I could not reveal my full code, so made a snippet to give an idea about what i wanted. Issue is fixed now.

Issue was: I wanted to append a JSP on certain condition inside `$(document).ready()` but the working of `$(document).ready()` is something like, it ensures executions of methods and conditions written inside it. 
Problem was:

Method "`myFunctionToProcessData`" and "`$('#divId').load('url/mypage.jsp');`" was called simultaneously , and HTML was not complete at the same time when method called and due to this, my method did not find division to set values and do other validations.

To solve this I have used below approach:

1. Appended html/jsp page using .load function.
2. used an ajax method in which i am getting data.

execution steps: 
1. Code appended HTML in some time (Using setTimeout function)
2. after execution of all lines in $(document).ready(), ajax function called
3. Now `myFunctionToProcessData` ca find divisions to set values and proper out put shown on the UI.

code:

```
$(document).ready(
            if(condition1){
                var var1= data //some json data;
                  setTimeout(function() {
                $('#divId').load('url/mypage.jsp');
                }, 10);
                if(condtition == true){
                 $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        contentType : "application/json",
                        data : "&sid=" + Math.random(),
                        url : "url", // change to full path of file on server
                        success : function (data) {
                    myFunctionToProcessData(var1); 
                    });         
            }
            }
)
```

This is just a workaround to make sure that `myFunctionToProcessData` executes only after jsp appended succesfully in it. 
now `myFunctionToProcessData` is executing at the end.